# Calling setState in componentDidUpdate for animations based on refs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I'm doing some custom animations in my React app involving updating margins on a component with `position: absolute`. It's a menu that can toggle in and out.

I have a `ref` for the element it's toggling behind, whose node height I'm grabbing in `componentDidMount`. I use this height to know how far to move my toggling component.

I noticed when my app renders the first time my component isn't animating right because the height value is always zero. When I toggle it subsequently it works because the `componentDidMount` fires and updates the height of the other node properly.

To fix this I moved my `divHeight` field into the state and started calling `setState` in `componentDidMount`, now my toggleable component renders correctly each time.

Is this an anti-pattern? I can't see how else I would update my UI based on physical attributes of the HTML nodes, since those are only available through `refs` in `componentDidMount`...

Answer (score 0):

There is another method to perform physical changes in html elements instead of using refs. Instead you can toggle classes on and off elements to do what you want, like toggling a menu in and out of frame.

Below is an example of how its done without the use of refs. Click the button and you can imagine the red div is your top navigation menu.

```js
class MenuExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onToggleMenu = this.onToggleMenu.bind(this);
    this.state = { menuToggle: false };
  }
  
  onToggleMenu(e) {
    this.setState({ menuToggle: !this.state.menuToggle });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onToggleMenu}>Open menu</button>
        <div className={`menu ${this.state.menuToggle && 'active'}`} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <MenuExample/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.menu.active {
 top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The issue with this is that my elements don't have fixed heights - so I wouldn't be able to do something like ```top: -100px```, so I need to get their heights after they've rendered.

Comment: Hmmm. If the height of the item varies, then i can only suggest you put a min and max-height on the item, then `top: - max-height` guarantees the item will be hidden while allowing for some variable height